# PHPSpec - Check if Method Returns a file

Tags: php, unit-testing, tdd, bdd, phpspec

I am new to phpspec, and I am trying to test if a method returns a file.  The method is essentially:

```
public function getFile(){
    return file_get_contents('myFile.pdf');
}
```

So my initial though was to test if `getFile()` returns a string since `file_get_contents` returns a string according to the [docs](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents).

So my test looks like this:

```
$this->getFile()->shouldHaveType("string");
```

But my test fails with the following message:

```
expected an instance of string, but got "%PDF-1.4"....
```

I have even tried `gettype(getFile())` and it returns `"string"`.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: you need to use `gettype(getFile())` first and then check it

Comment: I have tried that already and it returns "string"

Comment: do you got same error?

Comment: Your method does not return a file. It returns some string.

Comment: Yes, I know that.  And that is what I am trying to test for - a string.

Comment: `(null !== $subject) && ($subject instanceof $arguments[0]);` --- that's how the type is checked btw (in phpspec sources)

Comment: Never used phpspec but according its source you need to use `ScalarMatcher`. So probably `->beScalar('string')` may be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are checking for a type of class. But you really want to check if the data returned is of type string. @zerkms is correct. You should use a Scalar Matcher (http://www.phpspec.net/cookbook/matchers.html#scalar-matcher)

```
$this->getFile()->shouldBeString()
```